# .htaccess , How to redirect any .jpg page to its attachment page (HTML)

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

> www.domain.com/images/Apple.jpg

to

> www.domain.com/Apple.html

Here is the Live working example, This is what i exactly want
http://more-sky.com/data/out/2/IMG_21306.jpg

How it redirect to its parent page i.e (http://more-sky.com/WDF-21306.html)

Comment: do you have a set of records, that `this image` should be redirected to `that page`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in your Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^images/([^\.]+)\.(jpe?g|png) /$1.html  [QSA,L]
```

**Edit:** as noticed by Wh1T3h4Ck5, `QSA` (*Query String Append*) flag would be optional, as well as `L` (*Last*) would depend on the context and other rules present. Please, read about [RewriteRule flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) for more information.

---

**To clarify:** this solution assumes that an HTML document with the name of the image already exists. Something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apple</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/Apple.jpg" alt="Apple">
    </body>
</html>
```

This is not an optimal solution for a large number of images, but it seemed to fit OP's case.

Comment: `QSA` appends the query string (if any) to the redirected URL. You're right on pointing this out. It should be totally optional.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Asked just because `/$1.html` replacement has no GET parameters to be appended and seems logical to me that QSA directive does nothing in this rule ;) Anyway, answer is correct despite QSA.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this method also changing the extension of image file(image.jpg to image.html).. and image is not showing in the webpage

Comment: Well @Rohit, you obviously need to create an HTML page with the same name and `.html` extension for this to work. But please, read again your own question. You asked to redirect `www.domain.com/images/Apple.jpg` to `www.domain.com/Apple.html`.

Comment: @jordi nebot , i really appreciate your help,but i am getting broken image path on my webpage, after putting your code. 

Let me directly come to the point what i exactly want.
I want user to redirect to my web page when they click on VIEW FULL IMAGE on Google image Search.What i am getting right now , is user is directly falling to the jpg page.If you think there's any other way to do this , then please correct me

Comment: @Rohit I'd suggest you to edit your question adding more information on what you really want to achieve to see if me or anybody else can come up with a better solution... :)